# unique index on distinct combination

Tags: mysql, unique-index

I would like to ensure that a safe_id is only assigned to always the same user_id.
However, the same user_id, safe_id combination is allowed multiple times

ok:

```
user_id, safe_id, ...
1, 1
1, 2
1, 3
1, 2
1, 2
2, 5
2, 6
2, 6
```

not ok:

```
user_id, safe_id, ...
1, 1
1, 2
1, 3
1, 2
1, 2
2, 5
2, 3  --> this safe_id is assigned to two user_ids
2, 6
```

This is a query that would give me the combinations that break this restriction:

```
SELECT safe_id, COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) FROM T GROUP BY safe_id HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) > 1;
```

Is there some way to do this on the DB level? A normal unique index on user_id, safe_id is not possible because the combination is allowed multiple times.

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Maybe think about a trigger.